# AngularJs ng-repeat is not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to angularjs . I am stuck in ng-repeat directives.

Here is my code :

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>Looping Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>    
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function helloWorldExampleCtrl($scope){
        $scope.userName = "Vicky!"
          $scope.contacts = ["hi@email.com", "hello@email.com"];
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<div> 
   <h1 ng-controller="helloWorldExampleCtrl">Welcome {{userName}} ! <br/>

   Emails : <br>  
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts"> {{ contact }} </li>
   </ul>
  </h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output I am getting :

```
Welcome Vicky! ! 
Emails :
hi@email.com
hi@email.com
hello@email.com
hello@email.com
```

But excepted is :

```
Welcome Vicky! !
Emails :
hi@email.com
hello@email.com
```

What i am doing wrong?.....

Comment: I just reproduced your sample, and everything is fine http://plnkr.co/edit/gJNMOB8tlIytH7vtRCOT?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two versions of the AngularJS Library added to your page using the script tag.  Remove one to solve the issue:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>Looping Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function helloWorldExampleCtrl($scope){
        $scope.userName = "Vicky!"
          $scope.contacts = ["hi@email.com", "hello@email.com"];
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<div> 
   <h1 ng-controller="helloWorldExampleCtrl">Welcome {{userName}} ! <br/>

   Emails : <br>  
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts"> {{ contact }} </li>
   </ul>
  </h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[A Plunker with only one AngularJS import that works](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fz70hk5oL98Z42UV7lke?p=preview)

[A Plunker with two AngularJS Library Imports that duplicates your problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/bMjBTN2MsjiqyWsVGF00?p=preview)

Comment: Reboog711 , Can you tell me one more thing , what is difference between angular.min.js and angular.js file

Comment: @vicky Angular.min.js is a minified version the Angular library.  That means that it was run through a code processor to make variable names shorter, remove white space, and do similar things.  The purpose is to make the library have a very small file size for production purposes.  Angular.js is not minifed; and will be much easier to read during development--if you need to examine the Angular library.  I've used UglifyJS as a minifier in the past.  Google's Closure is another option.